# How to compute the density of a boolean matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, sparse-matrix

This is an example boolean matrix I'm talking about. There is a 4 by 4 sub-matrix in the lower left and upper right corner, and two outliers in the upper left and lower right corners respectively. I want to circle the two areas for the lower left and upper right corners and I'm not sure how I should do it.

```
[[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],\
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],\
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],\
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],\
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],\
 [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],\
 [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],\
 [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1],\
 [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

My current thinking is that apparently the points in the bottom left and top right regions are more dense, and if I can compute a 'density matrix', then I can perhaps set a density threshold to filter the two outliers in the top left and bottom right corners, and then I can use convex hull to circle the region I want.

But I doubt the feasibility of this idea, firstly I don't know if I can circle both regions, and secondly I don't know how to find this density matrix. If you have a better idea, please share it with me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2d convolution with a 4x4 matrix of ones. If you plot the densities, it forms a sort-of circle.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


density = convolve2d(matrix, np.ones((4, 4)), mode = 'same')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(density)
```

[image: Density plot]

Answer (score 0):

> current thinking is ... compute a 'density matrix',

Use [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)
to identify connected components.
That way you'll have an exact pixel count for each component.
Sort by count and retain just the large components.

Pypi
[offers](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill)
[more](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0)
[than](https://pypi.org/project/floodfill)
[one](https://pypi.org/project/flood-fill-filter)
implementation to choose from.

---

[Erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaeb1e0c1033e3f6b891a25d0511362aeb)
of "small" regions may also prove helpful.